# About the formula for the quadratic variation of Brownian motion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, quadratic-variation

The attached document (page 17 - remark 3.4.2) [fuente](http://financelab.nctu.edu.tw/www/Students/101%E6%A5%8A%E5%98%89%E9%8A%98/shreve3-34.pdf) shows a formula that is derived from the mean value theorem. However, as much as I have searched for reference to said formula, I cannot find how to connect it with said theorem. I know that the "inequality of the mean value theorem" exists, but its formula is different from the one applied in the document.

Where $$\left\|∏\right\| = \max_{(j=0,\ldots, n-1)}(t_{j+1}-t_j)$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} [f'(t^*_j)]^2 (t_{j+1}-t_j)^2  \le \left\|∏\right\|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} [f'(t^*_j)]^2 (t_{j+1}-t_j) $$

**What is the process to arrive at this inequality?
Thank you**.

Comment: You're just using that $\sum_j a_jb_j \leq \sup_j a_j \sum_j b_j$.

Comment: @Jose27 Is it some property?

Answer (score 1):

Fuentes uses the mean value theorem only to show that the equality
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}[f(t_{j+1})-f(t_j)]^2=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}[f'(t^*_j)]^2(t_{j+1}-t_j)^2
$$
holds. The inequality
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}[f'(t^*_j)]^2(t_{j+1}-t_j)^2\le \underbrace{\max_{j=0,...,n-1}(t_{j+1}-t_j)}_{||\Pi||}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}[f'(t^*_j)]^2(t_{j+1}-t_j)
$$
is trivial because for every $j$ you  clearly have $t_{j+1}-t_j\le \max\limits_{j=0,...,n-1}(t_{j+1}-t_j)\,.$

Comment: Where does the partition norm come from?
$$||\Pi||$$

They seem to perform this procedure:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} [f'(t^*_j)]^2 [(t_{j+1}-t_j)]^2 =\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} [f'(t^*_j)]^2 [(t_{j+1}-t_j)*(t_{j+1}-t_j)]$$
Next, they extract one of these elements from the summation, making it a maximum:

$$[(t_{j+1}-t_j)] = max...$$

¿Cómo es posible hacer esto matemáticamente?

Comment: @Christian . No $[(t_{j+1}-t_j)]$ is ***less or equal*** to $\max\,.$ Trivial isn't it ? The partition norm is ***defined***. It is clearly finite when the whole interval we partition is finite. The whole purpose of this exercise is to show that the quadratic variation of a differentiable function is zero.